# angular animation error loading in firefox

Tags: angularjs, firefox, angular-material, ng-animate

Today, I was testing my angular app in Firefox.

My angular app has a couple of md-button and md-tabs. One of the md-tab contains table as it's content. Whenever I switch from this md-tab to some other md-tab in firefox, the table flashes for few seconds in new md-tab.

After spending some time in debugging, I found the property "animation", disabling which the flickering got disabled. To make it work, I changed the property "animation" to none for md-tab-content.

Whenever I start this application in firefox, it shows a popup box containing information for angular-animate.

[image]

I have run my application in chrome and safari, and it is working great in those browsers.

Regards

Ajay